# Modify XElement to have different content

Tags: .net, xelement

I have an XElement which it's output is

```
<Email>address@email.com</Email>
```

. Base on some criteria I will possibly need to remove the email address and set it to null. I know I can yous set element.Value =""; but that will not do what I want. I want to modify it so the output will become:

```
<Email xsi:nil=\"true\" />
```

I don't want to create a brand new node because this is a referenced node within a document. and i want to keep the node where it is within the document.
I tried

```
emailItem.Add(new XAttribute("xsi:nil", "true"));
```

but I received the following exception

> The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a
>   name.
>   The following changes create the node almost correctly:

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";                                    
emailItem.Add(new XAttribute(xsi + "nil", true));
emailItem.Value =""; //How do I set to Null?
```

I end up with  `<Email xsi:nil="true"></Email>` instead  `<Email xsi:nil="true"/>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need to specify the `XName` differently; you can't just create an `XName` in a namespace like that.

I suspect you want this:

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
emailItem.Document.Root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi",
                            xsi.ToString()));
emailItem.Add(new XAttribute(xsi + "nil", true);
```

Complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("root"));
        XElement element = new XElement("email");
        doc.Root.Add(element);
        XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        element.Document.Root.Add(
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.ToString()));
        element.Add(new XAttribute(xsi + "nil", true));

        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <email xsi:nil="true" />
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, The problem is at this point I do not have an XML Document yet.Ii am working with fragments that I am putting together I have in lists that will be put together later. The emailItem.Document is null. I will add the whole function into my question. Excuse the poor programming, I am a newbie when it comes to XML XNode, XElements and such. there is probably better ways than what I am doing.

Comment: @greektreat: You could just use `xsi` without adding the `xmlns` part to start with - but it'll show up in a way you don't want until you do...

Comment: That Almost worked, I modified it to do that and I set the value blank, I ended up with  <Email xsi:nil="true"></Email> instead of  <Email xsi:nil="true"/>

Comment: Set *which* value blank? If you're just trying to remove child nodes, call `element.RemoveNodes()`.

Comment: Oh See I told you I was a Newbie, That worked :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the xsi to map to the XML schema instance namespace, so in this case you need to specify that:

```
    XElement root = new XElement("root");
    root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"));
    XElement emailItem = XElement.Parse(@"<Email>address@email.com</Email>");
    root.Add(emailItem);
    emailItem.Add(new XAttribute(XName.Get("nil", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"), "true"));
    Console.WriteLine(root);
```

Notice that you don't need the root element (I just added it so that the namespace declaration doesn't go to the `Email` element itself).